# JQUERY + JSON weird error

Tags: jquery, json

Everytime I try to show ingredients for each Diner.Lunch it keeps showing ingredients double for no reason. I really don't seem to be able to find the error.

```
 $('.Lunch_article').append("<h3>Ingredients</h3> <ul>");
```

So it's this part that show's double and then 1 time solo, but that is fine cause that's what the code is supposed to do (`$.each(data[0].Dishes[0].Lunch, function(i)`)

I don't know how to create a JSfiddle (with JSON), but I don't think it's neccesary, cause summed up it looks like this:

Ingredients
Ingredients

Ingredients

which I need it to look like this:
Ingredients

Ingredients

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".diner_section").empty();

    $.ajax(
                {
                    url:        'Menu.json',
                    dataType:   'json',
                    success:    function(data)
                    {   
                        $(".lunch_section h2").remove();
                        $('.lunch_section').append("<h2 class='sectiontitel on'> <span> Lunch </span> </h2>");  
                        $('article.Lunch_article').remove();
                        $.each(data[0].Dishes[0].Lunch, function(i)
                        {

                            $('.lunch_section').append("<article class='Lunch_article'> <img src='" 
                                + data[0].Dishes[0].Lunch[i].Image
                                + "' alt='food_image'> <h1>"
                                + data[0].Dishes[0].Lunch[i].Name
                                + "</h1> <p>"
                                + data[0].Dishes[0].Lunch[i].description
                                + "</p>");

                            $('.Lunch_article').append("<h3>Ingredients</h3> <ul>");
                            $.each(data[0].Dishes[0].Lunch[i].ingredients[0], function(k, val)
                            {
                                console.log(data[0].Dishes[0].Lunch[i].ingredients[0]);
                                $('.Lunch_article ul').append("<li>" + val + "</li>")
                            });


                        });         

                    },

                    // eventuele foutafhandeling....
                    error: function()
                    {
                        alert("Houston, we have a problem");
                    }   
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
  <section class="lunch_section">
    <h2 class="sectiontitel"> <span> Lunch </span> </h2>
    <article class="Lunch_article">
      <img src="Images/lunch/bentobox.jpg" alt="food_image"/>
      <h1> Bento Box </h1>
      <p>Bento is a single-portion takeout or home-packed meal common in Japanese cuisine. A traditional bento holds rice, fish or meat, with pickled or cooked vegetables, usually in a box-shaped container. Containers range from disposable mass produced to hand crafted lacquerware. Bento boxes are readily available in many places throughout Japan, including convenience stores, bento shops, railway stations, and department stores. However, Japanese homemakers often spend time and energy on a carefully prepared lunch box for their spouse, child, or themselves.<br /> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bento"> Read more </a></p>
      <h3>Ingredients</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Fish</li>
        <li>Seaweed</li>
        <li>Soy Sause</li>
        <li>Vegetables</li>
        <li>Fish</li>
      </ul>

    </article>

  </section>
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "Dishes":
        [
            {
                "Lunch": 
                [
                    {
                        "Name":"Bento Box",
                        "type":"main",
                        "Image":"Images/lunch/bentobox.jpg",
                        "description":"Bento is a single-portion takeout or home-packed meal common in Japanese cuisine. A traditional bento holds rice, fish or meat, with pickled or cooked vegetables, usually in a box-shaped container. Containers range from disposable mass produced to hand crafted lacquerware. Bento boxes are readily available in many places throughout Japan, including convenience stores, bento shops, railway stations, and department stores. However, Japanese homemakers often spend time and energy on a carefully prepared lunch box for their spouse, child, or themselves.",
                        "url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bento",
                        "ingredients": 
                                [
                                    {
                                        "no1":"Rice",
                                        "no2":"Fish",
                                        "no3":"Seaweed",
                                        "no4":"Soy Sause",
                                        "no5":"vegetables",
                                        "no6":"meat"
                                    }
                                ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Name":"Miso Soup",
                        "type":"entree",
                        "Image":"Images/lunch/miso.jpg",
                        "description":"Miso soup (misoshiru?) is a traditional Japanese soup consisting of a stock called \"dashi\" into which softened miso paste is mixed. Many ingredients are added depending on regional and seasonal recipes, and personal preference.",
                        "url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miso_soup",
                        "ingredients": 
                                [
                                    {
                                        "no1":"Dashi",
                                        "no2":"Tofu",
                                        "no3":"Miso Paste"
                                    }
                                ]
                    }

                ],


                "Diner": 
                    [
                        {
                            "Name":"Sake Nigiri",
                            "type":"Nigiri",
                            "Image":"Images/diner/sake_nigiri.jpg",
                            "description":"Nigirizushi (\"hand-pressed sushi\") consists of an oblong mound of sushi rice that the chef presses into a small rectangular box between the palms of the hands, usually with a bit of wasabi, and a topping (the neta) draped over it. Neta are typically fish such as salmon, tuna or other seafood. Certain toppings are typically bound to the rice with a thin strip of nori, most commonly octopus (tako), freshwater eel (unagi), sea eel (anago), squid (ika), and sweet egg (tamago). One order of a given type of fish typically results in two pieces, while a sushi set (sampler dish) may contain only one piece of each topping",
                            "url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi",
                            "ingredients": 
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "no1":"Rice",
                                            "no2":"Salmon",
                                            "no3":"Wasabi paste",
                                            "no4":"Soy Sause"
                                        }
                                    ]
                        },

                        {
                            "Name":"Sake Maki",
                            "type":"Maki",
                            "Image":"Images/diner/Sake_maki.jpg",
                            "description":"Makizushi (\"rolled sushi\"), norimaki (\"Nori roll\") or makimono (\"variety of rolls\") is a cylindrical piece, formed with the help of a bamboo mat known as a makisu. Makizushi is generally wrapped in nori (seaweed), but is occasionally wrapped in a thin omelette, soy paper, cucumber, or shiso (perilla) leaves. Makizushi is usually cut into six or eight pieces, which constitutes a single roll order. Below are some common types of makizushi, but many other kinds exist.",
                            "url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi",
                            "ingredients": 
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "no1":"Rice",
                                            "no2":"Seaweed",
                                            "no3":"Salmon"
                                        }
                                    ]
                        },

                        {
                            "Name":"Sake Temaki",
                            "type":"Temaki",
                            "Image":"Images/diner/sake_temaki.jpg",
                            "description":"Temaki (\"hand roll\") is a large cone-shaped piece of nori on the outside and the ingredients spilling out the wide end. A typical temaki is about ten centimeters (4 in) long, and is eaten with fingers because it is too awkward to pick it up with chopsticks. For optimal taste and texture, temaki must be eaten quickly after being made because the nori cone soon absorbs moisture from the filling and loses its crispness, making it somewhat difficult to bite through. For this reason, the nori in pre-made or take-out temaki is sealed in plastic film which is removed immediately before eating.",
                            "url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi",
                            "ingredients": 
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "no1":"Rice",
                                            "no2":"Salmon",
                                            "no3":"Wasabi paste",
                                            "no4":"Avocado",
                                            "no4":"Seaweed"
                                        }
                                    ]
                        } 

                    ] 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like

Comment: on an semi-related note, it looks like you're going to potentially be creating more than 1 `h1` tag with your loops. In terms of best practise `h1` tags should only appear once on a page.

Comment: [You already asked about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527882/json-wont-load). Asking again is not the way to go about it.

Comment: Hey I have put the HTML in it.
@Patrick Q that was an other question, I'am now further

Comment: Are you able to modify the JSON format to match what I put in the fiddle on your other question? If so, I strongly recommend that you do so.

Comment: I can't do that, I have to do it this way with no1, no2 etc. But that part I already got fixed.

Comment: This is typically something than you can sort by yourself by using the instruction debugger; at the top of your javascript code. Then go step-by-step ;).

Difficult to tell without the JSON payload. Can you attach the json file as well ?

Do all lunches have ingredient ?

Besides, it looks like the tag you add in your JS code is not closed.

Comment: Why is this wrong ? See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qau5ygxz/

Comment: The fiddle is showing my code without the script working, cause it only shows bento and not miso soup. (I remove that at the beginning of the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation for .append](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

You can create content and insert it into several elements at once:

```
 $( ".inner" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

Each inner  element gets this new content:

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>    
<div class="container">    
  <div class="inner">    
    Hello    
    <p>Test</p>    
  </div>    
  <div class="inner">    
    Goodbye    
    <p>Test</p>    
  </div>    
</div>
```

I believe that is your problem, each time you call

```
$('.Lunch_article').append("<h3>Ingredients</h3> <ul>");
```

the Ingredients header is being appended to all instances of Lunch article, not just the one you are currently looping through. So with two articles, you get Ingredients printed twice in the first one, and then once in the second. To fix this, you need to give each Lunch article a unique id and append only to that one.

Comment: Yup, that's the fix. You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ffLw8w86/4/